# How can I process this in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm using an API that returns a JSON string formatted like this:

```
{u'inboxMessages': [{u'fromAddress':
u'BM-2DBYkhiBZCyrBa8J7gFRGrFRSGqtHgPtMvwQ', u'toAddress':
u'BM-2DC7SCTj2gzgrGgMvUCARdrfrsgLyz3iMyN3', u'read': 0, u'msgid':
u'36659a4453e12a085d8fbfeefc58da8fb23f38bfb0984c2983e0ddc31c776038',
u'receivedTime': u'1377986524', u'message':
u'dGVzdGluZyAxIDIgMw0KDQotLQ0KSm9obiBQZXJyeQ0KDQo=\n', u'encodingType':
2, u'subject': u'bWVzc2FnZSAx\n'}, {u'fromAddress':
u'BM-2DBYkhiBZCyrBa8J7gNBrngtgttHgPtMvwQ', u'toAddress':
u'BM-2DC7SCTj2gzgrGgMvUCARdCrfthyz3iMyN3', u'read': 0, u'msgid':
u'2ebe10c788ed47c6c122e3b43ae6642cb15077536c7056ed5088ab2d339c4630',
u'receivedTime': u'1377986557', u'message':
u'VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgbmV4dCB0ZXN0DQoNCi0tDQpKb2huIFBlcnJ5DQoNCg==\n',
u'encodingType': 2, u'subject': u'dGVzdGluZyAzIDQgNQ==\n'},
{u'fromAddress': u'BM-2DBYkhithgyhyrBa8J7gNBrnSGqtHgPtMvwQ',
u'toAddress': u'BM-2DC7SCTj2gzgrtgtgMvUCARdCogLyz3iMyN3', u'read': 0,
u'msgid':
u'91dffd421c898aab0ffc43a363869a580abec6fa851aa6cf7cefe98263f96c81',
u'receivedTime': u'1377986599', u'message':
u'VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgM3JkIHRlc3QNCg0hjj0NCkpvaG4gUGVycnkNCg0K\n',
u'encodingType': 2, u'subject': u'dGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgM3Jk\n'}]}
```

I'm trying loop through each of these and list the 'fromAddress field. So far, I can list the first entry like this:

```
data = json.loads(api.getAllInboxMessages()) # The API call
print data['inboxMessages'][1]['fromAddress']
```

The above code will retrieve the fromAddress from the first message. But how can I retrieve the others? I know the answer is "just loop to the top of the index" but how do I know what the top of the index is?

How should I handle this to process ALL of the messages in this string?

Thanks!
Anthony

Answer (score 6):

Format the dictionary nicely and you'll see its structure easily:

```
{
    u'inboxMessages': [{
        u'fromAddress': u'BM-2DBYkhiBZCyrBa8J7gFRGrFRSGqtHgPtMvwQ',
        u'toAddress': u'BM-2DC7SCTj2gzgrGgMvUCARdrfrsgLyz3iMyN3',
        u'read': 0,
        u'msgid': u'36659a4453e12a085d8fbfeefc58da8fb23f38bfb0984c2983e0ddc31c776038',
        u'receivedTime': u'1377986524',
        u'message': u'dGVzdGluZyAxIDIgMw0KDQotLQ0KSm9obiBQZXJyeQ0KDQo=\n',
        u'encodingType': 2,
        u'subject': u'bWVzc2FnZSAx\n'
    }, {
        u'fromAddress': u'BM-2DBYkhiBZCyrBa8J7gNBrngtgttHgPtMvwQ',
        u'toAddress': u'BM-2DC7SCTj2gzgrGgMvUCARdCrfthyz3iMyN3',
        u'read': 0,
        u'msgid': u'2ebe10c788ed47c6c122e3b43ae6642cb15077536c7056ed5088ab2d339c4630',
        u'receivedTime': u'1377986557',
        u'message': u'VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgbmV4dCB0ZXN0DQoNCi0tDQpKb2huIFBlcnJ5DQoNCg==\n',
        u'encodingType': 2,
        u'subject': u'dGVzdGluZyAzIDQgNQ==\n'
    }, {
        u'fromAddress': u'BM-2DBYkhithgyhyrBa8J7gNBrnSGqtHgPtMvwQ',
        u'toAddress': u'BM-2DC7SCTj2gzgrtgtgMvUCARdCogLyz3iMyN3',
        u'read': 0,
        u'msgid': u'91dffd421c898aab0ffc43a363869a580abec6fa851aa6cf7cefe98263f96c81',
        u'receivedTime': u'1377986599',
        u'message': u'VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgM3JkIHRlc3QNCg0hjj0NCkpvaG4gUGVycnkNCg0K\n',
        u'encodingType': 2,
        u'subject': u'dGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgM3Jk\n'
    }]
}
```

Here, you just iterate through the list:

```
data = json.loads(api.getAllInboxMessages())

for message in data['inboxMessages']:
    print message['fromAddress']
```

Comment: Wow. Yeah, um just wow. Formatting properly does help, doesn't it? Thank you, that is the answer!

Comment: @MikeVella: I just pasted it into IPython. It formats long dictionaries automatically.